# C++ sending a vector across a socket connection

Tags: c++, sockets, vector

I am trying to send a vector across a socket, but am hitting a series of errors I am not sure how to resolve.

Vector and send over the socket are as so:

```
 int code = 52;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, static_cast<uint8_t>(224 + code / 16), static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16) };

comm_send1 = send(sock, data1.data(), data1.length(), 0);
```

Errors are:

```
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "uint8_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"  
Error (active)  E0135   class "std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>" has no member "length"    
Error   C2039   'length': is not a member of 'std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>' 
Error   C2660   'send': function does not take 3 arguments
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: The code you posted  doesn't attempt to send a vector across a socket - post something that does.

Comment: Sorry, english link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: do you take issue with their post, me asking the original question, me being new to c++ or me asking another question?

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have a member named `length()` - you probably mean `data1.size()`. `send` expects a `const char*`, not a `uint_8*` that you are passing - either make it `std::vector<char> data1`, or cast.

Comment: @gdogg371 It was the post, corrected it now

Comment: @IgorTandetnik std::vector<char> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, static_cast<uint8_t>(224 + code / 16), static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16) }; now creates a new set of errors

Comment: So fix them....

Comment: std::vector<char> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, static_cast<char>(224 + code / 16), static_cast<char>(code % 16) };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the send function doesn't except uint8_t* so you should cast the contents of the vector like this : (const char*)data1.data();
Also the vector class doesn't have length () method you should use size()